# converting bit type to varchar in ssis

Tags: ssis

i have two tables t1_STG, t2, in t1_STG one of my column is **check** which is of bit dataype, which holds data 1 or 0.

And in t2, column **check** is of varchar datatype. when am loading the data from t1_STG to t2, i haven't faced any errors while executing, but **check** column in t2 is coming wrongly, instead of 1's and 0's it is coming as **(-)**.

I tried to use derived column transformation for converting check column from t1_STG, but still facing same problem.

i use 2 DFT's, at first DFT level, i load the data into t1_STG, here my check column is coming correctly,i.e.., 1's and 0's.

But when i use the value of check from t1_STG instead of one it is coming as -1, and loading into my final t2 table as -1 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a derived column transformation:

```
(DT_STR,1,1252)([check] ? "1" : "0")
```

Add this derived column as a **new** column.

Comment: HI, when i tried to use your code, it is throwing error like, The conditional expression "check" of the conditional operator has invalid data type of "DT_14".

Comment: If it's "DT_I4", your column actually is defined as an integer, and not a bit (boolean). (DT_STR,1,1252)[check] should do the trick then.

Comment: my column is declared as varchar

Comment: If it's defined as a bit in your source, it should have the data type DT_BOOL in SSIS.

Comment: yep that worked , i tried like this (DT_BOOL)[check]==True ? "1" : "0"